# Reindex Multiindex dataframe on a specific level based on other dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Multiindex dataframe [id, currency] as an input. I want it to be filtered by the `price` dataframe index on the level currency. Any contribution would be appreciated.

`balance` dataframe:

```
                balance
id   currency   
1    JPY        2322
     USD        w3r234
     KWN        23423
2    POPO       234234 
     USDC       3w4234
     BTC         54545
     ETH         2323412
```

`price` dataframe:

```
JPY        0.3
KWN        0.5
POPO       0.2 
USDC       0.5
ETH        0.3
```

Desired output is the scaled `balance` dataframe:

```
                balance
id   currency   
1    JPY        2322
     KWN        23423
2    POPO       234234 
     USDC       3w4234
     ETH         2323412
```

My code:

```
idx = price.index
balance = balance.reindex(idx, level='currency', fill_value=0).sort_index()
```

Comment: @SaiSreenivas Yes that's the desired output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the values of the desired level and filter based on the items present in `price` dataframe:

```
df = balance[np.in1d(balance.index.get_level_values(1), price.index)]
```

Comment: Did not know about `np.in1d`. Thanks